# Deployed Qt5 Application Doesn't Print or Show Print Dialog

Tags: windows, deployment, qt4, qt5

I'm experiencing Qt4 to Qt5 troubles.  In my application when the user clicks the print button two things should happen, one is that a PDF gets written to disk (which still works fine in the new version, so I know that some of the printing functions are working properly) and the other is that a QPrintDialog should exec() and then send to a connected printer.

I see the dialog when I launch from my development machine.  The application launches on the deployed machine, but the QPrintDialog never shows and the document never prints.

I am including print support.

```
QT += core gui network webkitwidgets widgets printsupport
```

I have been using Process Explorer to see what DLLs the application uses on my development machine, and I believe that everything is present.  My application bundle includes:

- {myAppPath}\MyApp[MyApp.exe, Qt5PrintSupport.dll, ...]
- {myAppPath}\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
- {myAppPath}\plugins\imageformats[ qgif.dll, qico.dll,qjpeg.dll, qmng.dll, qtga.dll, qtiff.dll, qwbmp.dll ]

The following is the relevant code snippet:

```
void PrintableForm::printFile()
{
    //Writes the PDF to disk in every environment
    pdfCopy();

    //Paper Copy only works on my dev machine
    QPrinter paperPrinter;
    QPrintDialog printDialog(&paperPrinter,this);

    if( printDialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted ) {
        view->print(&paperPrinter);
    }
    this->accept();
}
```

My first thought is that the relevant DLLs are not being found come print time, and that means that my application file system is incorrect, but I have not found anything that shows me a different file structure.  Am I on the right track or is there something else wrong with this setup?

Comment: Are you sure about `{myAppPath}\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll`? Should be without the "plugins" part. Please set the env variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to a non-zero value and run the app from the console, so you can check that the plugin is indeed found and used.

Comment: Progress.  peppe, good call on moving printsupport\* back one directory. Now it gives me a print dialog ( Qt must be using the native dialog for that rather than emulating it ) but when I hit print nothing is happening. I tried setting the environment variable and launching via the command line, but I didn't get anything.  I take it that that step must be done from the development machine and not the deploy-machine?

Comment: In order for QT_DEPLOY_PLUGINS to output anything useful it was necessary to add     CONFIG += CONSOLE to the .pro file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was another classic Windows/Qt5 deployment problem with a combination of missing plugins and plugins placed in incorrect places.  By using the environmental variable QT_DEBUG_PLUGIN and adding CONFIG += CONSOLE to my PRO file I was able to see that on my development machine the application was loading qminimal.dll which I was not shipping.

The application root which I have defined as {myAppPath}\ is the root directory for plugins.  Therefore the correct file structure is:

- {myAppPath}\MyApp[MyApp.exe, Qt5PrintSupport.dll, ...]
- {myAppPath}\platforms[qwindows.dll,qminimal.dll]
- {myAppPath}\printsupport*
- {myAppPath}\imageformats*
- {myAppPath}\bearer*

Thanks peppe for the lead.