# QT Creator QPrintDialog appears on development machine, but not on other machines

Tags: qt, deployment, printing, missing-data

I am having trouble deploying an application on machines other than my development machine.

I have a Print button on several menus which works well on the development machine, when running in a Release build in QT Creator. However when I build the project into a .msi file using WiX and distributing it to other computers the Print dialog will not appear. Is this most likely a problem with my WiX file? The version of the .dll file I am using? The .pro file (which includes printersupport in it)? How is it that QT Creator can find and run the code needed for the dialog but other systems cannot?

Comment: Try packaging the .msi with something else apart from WiX, if the print dialog works, then you know the problem is from WiX so you know how to proceed from there

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I agree, that is a good way to find out if my WiX file is the problem, but I don't know of any other way to make a .msi file from Qt Creator, I kind of inherited this project from another programmer. Any suggestions of a good way to build the .msi without using WiX?

Comment: http://www.advancedinstaller.com

Comment: What version of qt are you using?

Comment: The About Menu states : Qt Creator 3.0.1
Based on Qt 5.2.1 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)

Built on Jan 31 2014 at 05:16:27

From revision 51af63bb9e

Copyright 2008-2014 Digia Plc. All rights reserved.

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175398/deployed-qt5-application-doesnt-print-or-show-print-dialog

Comment: qminimal.dll might be missing from the package you're shipping

Comment: Thank you for that link, it sounded like it could have been the issue, but I checked and the qminimal.dll is included in both the WiX file and in the install directory of the target machine. Could this still be the issue with versioning, or something related to that?

Comment: Did you try the other deployment tool i suggested?

Comment: I think it must be a missing plugin dll which is not necessary to start the application. Else the application will fail to start or youll get a missing plugin message. It is working in the IDE because you have the needed dlls in the PATH. Try copying the plugins folder from your Qt installation in the root dir of your App, or to the appropriate directory if you changed your plugin/library dir via qt.conf or programmatically.